# C# При изменении количества в TextBox авто пересчёт в DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, textbox

Задача такова, есть один `TextBox`, в нём указывается количество, изменив его в `DataGridView` в определённом столбике должен произойти пересчёт всего столбика по формуле соответствено количеству введенаму в `TextBox`. 
Есть варианты как реализовать ?
Или можно делать через Select из базы.
Но мой вариант тоже не подходит, кидает ошибку:

```
OdbcDataAdapter sdf = new OdbcDataAdapter("Select pre_kod,ing_pav, pre_ska * (" + Convert.ToDouble(GAM_SKA.Text) + ")/1000, san_kod from v_gaminiai where gam_kod='" + txt_pre_kod.Text.ToString() + "'", conn);
```

Нужно `pre_ska` умножить на значение из `TextBox` и поделить на 1000.

Comment: Ничего непонятно в вашем вопросе. Опишите, пожалуйста, подробнее что и для чего вы пытаетесь сделать

Comment: Придумал по другому. Это можно сделать сразу через Select из базы. Но теперь не получается сделать правильно. вот как я пробую:OdbcDataAdapter sdf = new OdbcDataAdapter("Select pre_kod,ing_pav, pre_ska * (" + Convert.ToDouble(GAM_SKA.Text) + ")/1000, san_kod from v_gaminiai where gam_kod='" + txt_pre_kod.Text.ToString() + "'", conn); нужно pre_ska умножить на число из Текстбокса и поделить на 1000

Answer (score 0):

Сам разобрался. Вот ответ, может кому понадобится:

```
("Select pre_kod,ing_pav, pre_ska=(pre_ska * " + Convert.ToDouble(GAM_SKA.Text) + " /1000), san_kod from v_gaminiai where gam_kod='" + txt_pre_kod.Text.ToString() + "'", conn);
```